# Creating a custom-shaped button with one rounded corner

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I need to create a button in WPF that has a custom shape. Specifically, I want it to have rounded corners, like an ellipse. Here is a picture:

[image]

Only the black area should be a click target; the white area should be transparent.

How would I go about creating a button control in WPF that has such a custom shape? I know how to create a regular rectangular button, but not one with a rounded corner like this.

Comment: This question has been discussed on Meta: [Reopening “poor” question with good answer?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399807/4642212).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use a ControlTemplate to achieve that:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Data="M 0,0 A 100,100 90 0 0 100,100 L 100,100 100,0" />
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Than you apply it to the button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}"/>
```

If you need some references to draw the "Path" check [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) MSDN link.

**Update**

To show the content you should use a ContentPresenter, something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid>
                        <Path Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            Data="M 0,0 A 100,100 90 0 0 100,100 L 100,100 100,0" />
                        <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

In the button:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyle}" Foreground="White">
        test
    </Button>
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks mate! it works. However, I would like to know how can I set a content for this? When I set a content to the button it doesn't show.

Comment: To show the content you should insert a ContentPresenter