# How to make my button grid fit my hexagon image in WPF-XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

[image: https://ibb.co/jkHJ1F]

I have a hexagon Image for my button as in picture. I want to remove click from corner edges, and to be clicked only when clicking on picture. I have tried few solution, by my clickable grid is always squared, and that's why my button click area is bigger then my picture.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                    <Grid x:Name="LayoutGrid"
                          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter"
                                          Focusable="True"
                                          HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                          RecognizesAccessKey="True"
                                          SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                                          VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                          Margin="0"
                                          IsHitTestVisible="True"
                                          ToolTip="Button">
                            <ContentPresenter.Content>
                                <Image Source="/WpfApp3;component/Images/hexagonImage.png"
                                       Stretch="None" />
                            </ContentPresenter.Content>
                        </ContentPresenter>
                        <Label Content="Label"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               Margin="60,130,60,51"
                               Width="180"
                               Height="40"
                               HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"
                               RenderTransformOrigin="0.428,-0.075"
                               FontSize="18"
                               FontFamily="Arial Narrow"
                               IsHitTestVisible="False" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsDefaulted"
                                 Value="true" />
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver"
                                 Value="true" />
                        <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                                 Value="true" />
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
                                 Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"
                                    TargetName="contentPresenter"
                                    Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Check out this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17532063/custom-shaped-button-in-wpf) link. It's about using a ControlTemplate to shape a button to your likings, in your case a hexagon.

Comment: @ivica, try set `Clip` property on LayoutGrid using hex-shape geometry ([Clip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.clip(v=vs.110).aspx))

Comment: I have found what was the problem. Even tho background edges are transparent they are still there and that makes a problem. I have made custom contron(Button) and inside i have drawn a path exactly same as my picture and centered same as picture, and then have set my path to be clickable and transparent and my picture not clickable, and that solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is answer that i've done, in case someone will need something similar in future.
1.rst i have made customControl deriving from Button. And inside i have 2 DependencyProperties just to change Image on click.

```
public ImageSource Image
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(ImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ImageProperty, value); }
        }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Image", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomControl), 
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));

        public ImageSource NewImage
        {
            get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(NewImageProperty); }
            set { SetValue(NewImageProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for NewImage.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty NewImageProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("NewImage", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(CustomControl),
                 new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ImageSource), FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```

Inside of Generic.xaml i havse structured code like this ( This works for me and my project).

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:wpf.core">


<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:CustomControl}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                      VerticalAlignment="Center"
                      Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=image}"
                      Height="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=image}">

                    <Image x:Name="image"
                           IsHitTestVisible="False"
                           Stretch="None"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                                <Setter Property="Source"
                                        Value="{Binding Image, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsPressed, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"
                                                 Value="true">
                                        <Setter Property="Source"
                                                Value="{Binding NewImage, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" />
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Image.Style>
                    </Image>
                    <ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                      ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding ContentStringFormat}"
                                      Height="48"
                                      IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                      Margin="38.667,0,38,46.666"
                                      VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                      HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                      MaxHeight="48"
                                      MaxWidth="188" />
                    <Path Data="M2,88.60254L152,2 302,88.60254 302,261.817621 152,350.410161 2,261.807621z"
                          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
                          Stretch="Fill"
                          Fill="Transparent"
                          Focusable="True"
                          StrokeThickness="0"
                          Margin="25.333,-24.001,25.333,-23.999"
                          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                          Opacity="0">
                        <Path.RenderTransform>
                            <TransformGroup>
                                <ScaleTransform />
                                <SkewTransform />
                                <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                <TranslateTransform />
                            </TransformGroup>
                        </Path.RenderTransform>
                    </Path>
                </Grid>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed"
                             Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Foreground"
                                Value="White" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Trick was to make path (Hexagon) that will be exactly same as my pictures, and set that path to be clickable but transparent, and picture to be visible but not clickable, and that solve my problem, now i have fully functional Hexagon button.

Sample of code in main window, just to show purpose.

```
    <Grid>
    <cc:CustomControl Image="/WpfApp3;component/Images/hexPicture1.png"
                      NewImage="/WpfApp3;component/Images/hexPicture2.png"
                      ToolTip="Button"
                      Content="Some content"
                      FontFamily="Arial narrow"
                      FontSize="18"/>
</Grid>
```